# Как использовать оформление интерфейса из одной темы, а подсветку из другой темы в VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Нашел красивую тему для VSC, но она имеет ужасную подсветку синтаксиса. Как бы я мог использовать другую тему только для изменение подсветки синтаксиса, а остальное оформление оставив от первой темы?

Answer (score 2):

Все достаточно просто. По порядку (на примере цвета шрифта для комментариев):

1. Установите тему, где вам нравится подсветка.
2. Нажмите <kbd>F1</kbd>
3. В строке введите `Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings`
4. В открывшеся json-файле найдите `"scope": "comment"`. У меня значение `"foreground": "#FF9900"`
5. Заберите все цвета/стили, которые вам нужны
6. Переключитесь на другую тему
7. Нажмите <kbd>F1</kbd>
8. В строке введите `Preferences: settings Open (JSON)`
9. В самый низ документа и добавляете нужные значения цветов для определенных "scope". В моем примере это `comments`

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments" :"#FF9900",
    }
```

10. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
11. Радуетесь изменениям

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основные `scopes`:

1. `variables`
2. `string`
3. `constant.*`
4. `keyword`

это все можете переопределять в `settings.json` файле.

Про автоматические слияния тем, я, к сожалению, не слышал

Comment: что делать с комментариями на python такого синтаксиса """ комментарий """?