# Изменить цвет текущего параметра в подсказке

Tags: visual-studio-code

Кажется этот текст выделен жирным, но в другой используемой теме, текущий параметр выделялся другим цветом, что за это отвечает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Взять допустим: Dark+ (default dark)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1376841/209304. Там я разбирал как найти и поменять цвета. И в стилях можно покапатья для различных scope

Comment: @Dmitry, это не имеет смысла, как я в этом списке должен найти то, что отвечает за оформление данного участка? "editor.action.inspectTMScopes" не работает на эту всплывающую штучку.

Comment: Поищите по цвету (который возьмите пипеткой из скриншота). Если совпадет несколько, то думать по названию...

Comment: Доберусь до компа, напишу ответ.

Comment: По цвету я не попал (ибо все пиксели считай смешанные), но на угад получилось..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За это отвечает: `editorHoverWidget.highlightForeground`.