# Комментарии vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как поменять цвет коментариев vscode?

Comment: Для разноцветных комментариев есть расширение Better Comments.

Comment: я писал немного больше чем вам надо [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1376841/209304), начиная с пункта 7 описаны действия для смены цвета для комментариев. Можете воспользоваться им и если поможет оцените тот ответ